# Why does using do until give me only one observation in SAS?

Tags: sas

Hello I am trying to solve a problem using iteration with do until but I don't get any results. Also I am learning SAS at the moment on my own using books, documentation and videos so I am new to this language. My problem is :

**A car delivers a mileage of 20 miles per galon. Write a program so that the program stops generating observations when distance reaches 250 miles or when 10 gallons of fuel have been used
Hint Miles = gallon * mpg**

**I used the following code:**

```
data mileage;
mpg = 20;
do until (miles le 250);
miles +1;
do until (gallon le 10);
gallon + 1;
miles = gallon * mpg;
end;
end;
output;
run;
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Many thanks for your time and attention !

Comment: What output do you want/expect?

Comment: @Tom - I would like the program to provide to provide me observations until distance reaches 250 miles or when 10 gallons of fuel have been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you waited until after the DO loops finished to write out any observations. If you want to write multiple observations you should move your `output` statement inside the do loop.

Also your program is never initializing `gallon` so `mpg` will always be missing and so less than 250 which means your outer DO loop will only execute once.

Your question as written can be answered without a program since 10*20 is less than 250.  Assuming that you also want to change the `mpg` values then perhaps this is more what you wanted?

```
data mileage;
  do mpg = 20 by 1 until (miles ge 250);
    do gallon=1 to 10 until (miles ge 250);
      miles = gallon * mpg;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

The ability to combine both an iterative loop with an UNTIL condition is one of the many nice features of the data step DO loop.

Comment: @Tom- I did but now it gives me only one value like  20 20 1 not the complete observations in terms of iteration.

Comment: Edited to explain why your program will stop in one loop.  Also added example program to generate more results.

Comment: This is great Tom ! According to your answer if I just write                                                              data mileage;
 mpg = 20;
    do gallon=1 to 10 until (miles ge 250);
      miles = gallon * mpg;
      output;
  end;
run;   This would give me the answer without changing the mileage. I would take both the answer anyways. Have a great day God bless you ! Thanks for your help!